# sql where against two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have created a SP to return some customer data for one company. I am passing company id and the customer id in to the SP. There are two types of customer ids in the table I am querying. The two types are saved in different columns.

For an example say I have the following columns in my table.

ID,Comments,CustomerTypeAId,CustomerTypeBId

Either of the customer IDs can be null in one row. The customer Id I am passing in to the SP could be a Type A customer or Type B customer. So in my WHERE clause I need to specify if the CustomerTypeAId is null then query the CustomerTypeBId.

```
@CusId int=0
SELECT * FROM TEST
WHERE (How to put this part?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OR` in your `where` clause since it can be any of the two columns.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TEST
WHERE  CustomerTypeAId = @id OR
       CustomerTypeBId = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following does what you want:

```
select *
from test
where CustomerTypeAid = @CustId or CustomerTypeBid = @CustId
```

NULL is often a problem in boolean statements; however, it works fine with OR.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE @CusId IN (CustomerTypeAId, CustomerTypeBId);
```

However, why are you storing these values in separate columns? Are you going to add yet another column when you introduce Type C? Instead, you should just have a type column and a CustomerID column. That way, when you don't care what type they are, you just match on the CustomerID column.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE CustomerTypeAId = @id 
      OR (CustomerTypeAId IS NULL AND CustomerTypeBId = @id)
```